# How to find only patterns that are not commented?

Tags: regex, vim

I have some code where the same condition ABC is used as part of an if clause, at the end of it (as a comment) and in obsolete sections (which I do not want to remove yet). An example could look like this:

```
if (ABC) //this is the only line that should be matched, this comment should not change the outcome of the search
 {
   lots of code
 } // if (ABC)


//if (ABC)
// {
//   lots of obsolete code
// } // if (ABC)
```

How can I tell vim to search for the pattern ABC only where is is not commented out via `//` occurring before it on the same line?

`^.*\(\/\/\)\@!.*ABC` did not work, because the `.*` are also fulfilled by `//` and `^\(\/\/\)\@!*ABC` complains about "Nested *".

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the example in your question, this line works:

```
/\v(\/\/.*)@<!ABC
```

or without `very magic`:

```
/\(\/\/.*\)\@<!ABC
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! For reference: `\@<!` matches if the preceding expression is not fulfilled. It does not increase the length of the match that is returned.